# Keyboard layout not launching at startup after update to Debian 11!

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

After update to Debian 11 the keyboard layout is not launching at startup. I use the cinnamon desktop environment. I found out that I always have to go to Settings/Keyboard/Layouts and shift the keyboard layouts with up-down arrows, then the keyboard layout icon is showing up in the toolbar and everything is back to normal. Why the keyboard layout is not launching at startup and how to fix this once and for all?